# Surveys: problems, conjectures, and questions in some areas of nonlinear analysis

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, big-list, nonlinear-analysis

I would like to create a "*`big-list`*" of ***resources*** (e.g., *survey papers*, *webpages*, conference *proceedings*, *monographs*, etc.) that collect and offer some context and overviews of:

> ***open problems***, ***conjectures***, and ***questions*** that have recently arisen in ***nonlinear analysis***.

---

***Side note*:** In particular<sup>(*)</sup>, I'm very curious about "what's going on" in *nonlinear elliptic PDE*, *nonlinear hyperbolic equations*, *solitary waves*, *Lagrangian* and *Hamiltonian Systems*, and *Maxwell's equations*.

---

<sup>(*)But this should not be seen as a restriction if you have good material to share on other related topics.</sup>

Comment: By the way, a list of some open problems in PDE appered today in arXiv - http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.06540v1.pdf You may find some of them interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me provide a few references about the *$p$-Laplace operator*.

1. Some open problems concerning $p$-Laplacian are listed in [Abstracts of Mini-Workshop "The p-Laplacian Operator and Applications", 2013](http://www.mfo.de/document/1307b/OWR_2013_08.pdf), on the pages 476-480.
   (Problem 3 about *Nodal line* of second $p$-eigenfunction is explained also [here](http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/mi/Forschung/Kawohl/kawohl/variationsPLap.pdf), p. 10.)
2. Other open problems like a *unique continuation property* can be found in classical book [Notes on the $p$-Laplace equation](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~lqvist/p-laplace.pdf), by P. Lindqvist, p. 70.
3. Some open questions on the *Fredholm alternative* for $p$-Laplacian are discussed [in this article](http://www.iam.fmph.uniba.sk/amuc/_vol-76/_no_1/_drabek/drabek.pdf).